# How to interpret ssrm_heating.log on Samsung devices?

Tags: samsung, logging

I have the below log records of `ssrm_heating.log` on `/data/system/` folder from Samsung Galaxy S5.

```
....
....
2019-11-11 16:06:05  >>> [Call] CallStateOffHook : false
2019-11-11 16:06:05 [PKG] com.facebook.katana
2019-11-11 16:06:06 [LCD] ON
2019-11-11 16:06:10 [LCD] OFF
2019-11-11 16:06:10 [COM] [(-1->-1)(33,30,28, 0, 0, 11, 450)([ -83, ---],R:  0K,W:289K),(BL:  0)(RUT:   0,   0,  22,   2)] [XXXXNXX0XWX / CF:  -1,CC:-1,GF: -1,LB: -1,CG:100,TS:20,DF:99,TM:1,FS:0,RC:0,SB:0,CD:0,]  default ScreenOff 
                    [NET] com.facebook.katana : 223 KB, com.google.android.gms : 62 KB, com.facebook.orca : 1 KB, 
2019-11-11 16:07:23 [COM] [(-1->-1)(30,30,26, 0, 0, 10, 450)([ -81, ---],R:  0K,W:204K),(BL:  0)(RUT:   0,   0,  20,   2)] [XXXXNXX0XWX / CF:  -1,CC:-1,GF: -1,LB: -1,CG:100,TS:20,DF:99,TM:1,FS:0,RC:0,SB:0,CD:0,]  default ScreenOff 
                    [NET] com.facebook.katana : 141 KB, com.nest.android : 49 KB, com.google.android.gms : 8 KB, 
                    [TOP] [top=8%] [kswapd0=8%] [flipboard.app=7%] [mmcqd/0=5%] [/system/bin/mediaserver=2%] 
2019-11-11 16:07:53 [COM] [(-1->-1)(26,29,26, 0, 0,  9, 450)([ -81, ---],R:  0K,W:  9K),(BL:  0)(RUT:   0,   0,  18,   2)] [XXXXNXX0XWX / CF:  -1,CC:-1,GF: -1,LB: -1,CG:100,TS:20,DF:99,TM:1,FS:0,RC:0,SB:0,CD:0,]  default ScreenOff 
                    [NET] com.google.android.gms : 6 KB, com.facebook.katana : 1 KB, com.google.android.tv.remote : 1 KB, 
                    [TOP] [top=12%] [system_server=9%] [com.android.systemui=0%] [cfinteractive=0%] [irq/33-cpubw_hw=0%] 
2019-11-11 16:10:11 [PKG] com.android.incallui
2019-11-11 16:10:14 [LCD] ON
2019-11-11 16:10:14 [COM] [(-1->-1)(29,26,26, 0, 0,  9, 450)([ -81, ---],R:  0K,W: 34K),(BL:226)(RUT:   0,   0,  18,   2)] [XXXXNXX0OWX / CF:  -1,CC:-1,GF: -1,LB: -1,CG: 70,TS:20,DF:99,TM:1,FS:0,RC:0,SB:0,CD:0,]  default 
                    [NET] com.google.android.gms : 14 KB, com.facebook.katana : 9 KB, com.google.android.tv.remote : 3 KB, 
2019-11-11 16:10:25  >>> [Call] CallStateOffHook : true
2019-11-11 16:10:26 [LCD] OFF
2019-11-11 16:10:26 [COM] [(-1->-1)(29,26,26, 0, 0,  9, 450)([ -81, ---],R:  0K,W: 69K),(BL:  0)(RUT:   0,   0,  18,   2)] [XXXXNXX0XWO / CF:  -1,CC:-1,GF: -1,LB: -1,CG: 70,TS:20,DF:99,TM:1,FS:0,RC:0,SB:0,CD:0,]  default ScreenOffInCall 
                    [NET] com.google.android.gms : 66 KB, com.google.android.tv.remote : 1 KB, com.gotv.nflgamecenter.us.lite : 1 KB, 
2019-11-11 16:11:54 [LCD] ON
....
....
```

Does anyone know how to interpret the logs?

Comment: External references mentioning this file: [S98_clean_data.sh](http://netlab.linkpc.net/download/software/entware/opt/etc/init.d/S98_clean_data.sh), [XDA Forums](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/locked-until-further-notice-system-shell-exploit-all-samsung-mobile-devices-no-bl-unlock-required.4543071/page-25)